# What's the best version neutral method for deploying a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, localdb

On my development box, I always run the latest version of SQL Server. I often deploy databases from my dev box to a live/staging area for review or testing. I've done this many times and it has always been a painful process, but I am realizing that I need to find an easier, more reliable and consistent way of performing this basic operation.

I normally use WebMatrix purely for deployment and it's worked fine, but I've been having problems getting it to work on my server for some reason. Consequently, I am seeking an alternative solution.

Creating a SQL dump file would probably work, but it's not an acceptable solution a database contains images and easily exceeds 2 gigs of data which would take forever.

The Import/Export utility fails due to issues with incomplete schema copies, identity inserts and checks. The solutions offered for these issues has failed to work in my particular case.

The Backup and Restore method also fails due to some strange incompatibilities between SQL Server 2008 and 2012. SQL Server 2008 Management Studio throws exceptions during the restore process of a 2012 database. It's odd that this happens, even though I set the compatibility of the database to version 2008.

I haven't tried the Detaching, copying and reattaching files method, but I haven't bothered trying since it would probably fail for the same reasons the backup and restore method did.

Are there other alternatives out there? Also, why is this so unbelievable hard for a task that is so common and important, especially in this day in age of 2013?  Get real Microsoft!

Comment: You should try lowering the database compatibility level to 100 and then using detach/copy/attach method.

Comment: The compatibility level only restricts the **features** that are at your disposal in the new version; but it does ***NOT*** make it possible to restore a 2012 database on a 2008 server. This ***CANNOT*** be done - the file are too different in their internal structure.

Answer (score 2):

We changed our method of deploying and moving databases between servers, instances and versions by adopting the tools from RedGate. They are expensive, but worth it IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

My team creates scripts for ~everything.
Database Creation, Alter, Inserts, etc, etc.
And we write all scripts that check for the existence of things before trying to create them.
Aka, we can run the scripts over and over and get the same results.

And we deploy to different environments by using SqlCmd.exe.

EDIT

See:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/versioning-databases-views-stored-procedures-and-the-like.aspx

and

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/01/30/three-rules-for-database-work.aspx

=============

If that is "too much" then I agree with the other poster, RedGate is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Points below aside, have you considered the Database Projects within VS2012? they allow you to script off the tables, sp's, triggers, users etc you want, generate sql cmd scripts, make changes and schema compare and version control your database code, I'd certainly recommend it

> "Creating a SQL dump file would probably work, but it's not an
>   acceptable solution a database contains images and easily exceeds 2
>   gigs of data which would take forever."

Why is this a problem? where are you transferring the file from and to and over what connection?

> "The Backup and Restore method also fails due to some strange
>   incompatibilities between SQL 2008 and 2012. SQL 2008 Management
>   Studio throws exceptions during the restore process of a 2012
>   database. It's odd that this happens, even though I set the
>   compatibility of the database to version 2008"

This shouldn't be an issue if file is created in 2008 prior to restoring. If you create a new DB in your 2008 instance, then take a backup from that and restore it to a 2012 instance with 2008 compatiblity, then you should be able to use it there, back it up from the 2012 instance and restore to 2008 again afterwards.

Comment: The compatibility level only restricts the **features** that are at your disposal in the new version; but it does ***NOT*** make it possible to restore a 2012 database on a 2008 server. This ***CANNOT*** be done - the file are too different in their internal structure.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was thinking of creating on 2008, restoring onto 2012 in 2008 mode, and round tripping that file.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald - nope, once the database has been restored onto the 2012 instance, it's structurally a 2012 database file. Nothing after that point will make it compatible again with a 2008 instance.

Comment: Hmm, that's a pain I was under the impression this worked, as I believe it used to in 2008 (requires citation!)

Comment: Restoring a SQL Server backup from a newer version onto an older one has **never worked** - regardless of compatibility levels etc. The internal file formats are just too different...

Comment: Are you telling me that Microsoft didn't consider backwards compatibility exporting as an option? We're not talking about a couple of guys working out of their basement here, this is a multimillion dollar corporation with unlimited resources.